# Parent - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make it so when I click the exit button, it goes through the parents and selects the wrapper class, then removes and adds a class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="app-icon-container">
     <div class="app-icon-wrapper active">
          <img class="app-icon" src="http://www.antivirus-blog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/google-chrome-logo.png">
     </div>
     <div class="app-hover-window">
          <div class="exit-btn"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.exit-btn').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.app-icon-wrapper').removeClass('active').addClass('un-active');
    });
```

Comment: Close the img tag properly. It should be <img class="app-icon" src="http://www.antivirus-blog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/google-chrome-logo.png" /> . Notice the "/>" in the end.

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha - optional in HTML5

Comment: @adeneo Okay thanks , didn't knew that

Comment: `this` does not refer to `.exit-btn` in that context. I'm guessing that you are presented with an error message. Can you please post what you are seeing (e.g. error message / wrong behaviour)?

Comment: @MaxLeske - Why on earth wouldn't `this` be the clicked element ?

Comment: @adeneo I just try to be very careful about what I assume `this` to be in javascript. But you're right of course, I didn't quite think that through.

Answer (score 0):

`.app-icon-wrapper` is not a parent of `.exit-btn`, so `closest()` won't work, it only works on parents.
You could get the container instead, and then find the wrapper

```
$('.exit-btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.app-icon-container')
           .find('.app-icon-wrapper')
           .removeClass('active')
           .addClass('un-active');
});
```

or something like (not as dynamic)

```
$('.exit-btn').on('click', function() {
     $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('active').addClass('un-active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your exit-btn is withing your wrapper you can use

```
$(this).parents('.app-icon-wrapper').remove......
```

But in your case here

```
$(this).parent().find('.app-icon-wrapper').remove....
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be changed to the following code:

```
$('.exit-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().closest('.app-icon-wrapper').removeClass('active').addClass('un-active');
});
```

Because the element you want to reference is the sibling for the current element's parent. Not itself.